# How can I force <a> links to files trigger download in the browser (and not open)

Tags: c#, asp.net, download, anchor

I knowt it may be a repeated question but I couldn't find a solution to my case.

Here's what I am doing:I want to create a page where admin of the site can upload files and make a description for each file,and then users can download these files.I created an admin page with a `fileupload` control that saves the files in `downloads/files`.Then I created a database with three columns: 1-`downloadtitle` 2-`downloadmain` 3-`name`.The admin can enter download title and download main(the description of the file) for each file.and the `name` column will be filled automatically with the uploaded file's name.
Now here is what I did for the download page(after getting the data from the database using code behind):

```
<asp:Repeater ID="downloadsRepeater" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="downloadTitle"><%#Eval("downloadtitle") %></div>
        <div class="downloadMain"><%#Eval("downloadmain") %>
            <div class="downloadButtom" dir="ltr"><a href="/Downloads/Files/<%#Eval("name") %>">Download</a></div>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <SeparatorTemplate>
        <div class="separator"></div>
    </SeparatorTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

You can get the idea of how the page looks form the above code(I don't want the download links to redirect the user to another page.I want users to just click the download and the the file gets downloaded!)
This method I used is working with doc files, but it is not working for PDF files for example!(Pdf files will be opened by the browser instead of download)
So I want to know if theyre's a way of doing this the way I want it?

Comment: Some browsers will always open the PDF in the browser, regardless of how you configured the server. I've had this with Adobe Reader, where I set Firefox to always ask what to do with a PDF file, but it still opened in the browser without asking me anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know it is not possible by just setting some special string to the href property of an `<a>` tag.

But you can get your desired behaviour by replacing the link by an asp.net linkbutton and a postback in which you call the following method:

```
public static void DownloadFile(string filename, string path)
{
    Response.ContentType = "application/unknown";
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
    Response.TransmitFile(path);
    Response.End();
}
```

`path` is the full path to the file you want to send to the client and `filename` is the name which the file should have when it is sent (can be different from the original name).

Comment: Can you write the link button code too?I don't know where I can apply this method.thanks in advance

Comment: I mean I don't know how I can insert a method in a postback using the linkbuttom.I'd be glad if you showed me the way to that too!

Comment: @user2078785 Sorry for the late reply, I was off some days. Just drag a linkbutton from the toolbox onto your aspx page and then doubleclick it. This will create a method in your aspx.cs file which handles the click event. In this method you should call the function from above.

Comment: thanks for your reply,but there is a problem here!As you can see,I am using a repeater,and in it I am generating a dynamic <a> element for each file.The problem is I Don't know how can I do this with the link buttons.Any ideas about that?

Comment: @user2078785 Sorry, forgot the repeater. I'm not so familiar with this control. But what I guess you have to do is to replace the `<a>` tag by something like: `<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonDownload" runat="server" onclick="LinkButtonDownload_Click" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("name")%>'" CommandName="filename">Download</asp:LinkButton>`. As you can see I used the `CommandName` and `CommandArgument` properties to pass parameters. Those you can access in the click event by casting the sender to a linkbutton.

Answer (score 0):

Make the html hyperlink runat ="server"